# Android button setEnabled not greyed in Lollipop

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop

My buttons are not greyed in Android 5.1 (but greyed in 4.4.4) when I use myButton.setEnabled(false).
The behaviour is ok if I remove :
`<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>`

Comment: It seems to be a known bug : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176472

Comment: im having same thing